# How to create autonumbering with Python in Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to create an automatic numbering system with leading zeros in Python and openpyxl.

What is the best way to define the columns?
I would like to name them first and then say for each column what needs to be done.

Go to column 1 and put a numbering in it from 00001 to 00500.
Go to column 2 and put a numbering in there from 00501 to 01000.
...

In my opinion if I have these I can make any variants I want.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Numbers"
ws.append(['N1','N2'])

#create Leading zero's
#zero_filled_number = number_str.zfill(5)
#print(zero_filled_number)

# Here I get stuck
for i in ws.append_columns(0)
i = range (1,500,1) number_str.zfill(5)

#ws.append_columns(1)
#for N2 in range (501,1000,1) number_str.zfill(5)

wb.save('Auto_numbers.xlsx')
```

Comment: What did you think `i = range (1,500,1) number_str.zfill(5)` would achieve? Was it supposed to be in the `for` loop that's missing a colon?

Comment: Hello Grismar, I have made several attempts and also with for loop but I still can't manage to write it correctly. That's why I wrote the code so that you would understand what I want to do. 1) say which column, 2) determine the range (start point, end point,increase by 1 step). (and use of leading zeros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
test_file = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = test_file.active

sheet['A1'] = 'ID'
counter = sheet.max_row
while counter < 10:
    for row in sheet.rows:
        counter += 1
        sheet[f'A{counter}'] = f'N{counter}'
        sheet.append([f'N{counter}'])
        
test_file.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hello Robin, thank you for your input but I can't get it working.

Comment: @C_Python What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Make sure you already have an xlsx file. Then, just link to it. It should work. Lemme know what the error you're getting though.

Comment: I have a excel file in same directory (test.xlsx) I'm using pyCharm and it shows this error :  
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback error here, please?

Comment: I changed the filepath in the comments. (part1)
__exception__ = {tuple: 3} (<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>, ('invalid syntax', (‘/…./EXCEL_nr002.py', 15, 27, "        
sheet[f'A{counter}'] = f'N{counter}'\n")), <traceback object at 0x11026bc20>)
entry_point_fn = {str} ''
file = {str} '/…./EXCEL_nr002.py'
globals = {dict: 5} {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__file__': ‘/…./EXCEL_nr002.py', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
is_module = {bool} False

Comment: locals = {dict: 5} {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__file__': ‘/…./EXCEL_nr002.py', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
module_name = {NoneType} None
self = {PyDB} <__main__.PyDB object at 0x11024ded0>

Comment: Is this part of a larger code you're writing? Have you run this sample by itself? It runs fine on my end. I also need to see the entire traceback error as one.

Comment: Hello Robin, I try run your script with IDLE (to reduce the pycharm errors) (Still learning) and I get this message :  from openpyxl import Workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' when I tested it in PyCharm I have a module openpyxl and openpyexcel - The script that works in PyCharm was with openpyexcel libary.

Comment: See if it works if you install the module. https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/

Comment: It's already installed : Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same without openpyxl -- just write the info in a text file tab delimited. 
with open('numbers3.txt', 'w') as f:
   # f.write('Start')
   f.write("N1" + "\t" + "N2" + "\t" + "\n")
and then the Numbering as above.

Comment: I try now to make 2 variables --- 
1 autonumbering 0001 tot 0500 and 
2 autonumbering 0501 tot 1000
CODE:

N1 = "TEST"
N2 = "TEST2"

with open('numbers4.txt', 'w') as f:
   # f.write('Start')
   f.write((N1) + "\t" + (N2) + "\t" + "\n")

Comment: Hello Robin, I leave this for the moment. Thank you for helping me. I first write in IDLE and try not to use excel.

Comment: That's strange. I really don't know what to tell you. Alright, glad to help.